# Error with mongrel_rails Fedena

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, fedena

When running the command `mongrel_rails start`, I get the following error

```
    mongrel_rails start
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3000
** Starting Rails with development environment...
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:493:in `all_specs': undefined method `gems' for #<Rails::VendorGemSourceIndex:0x7f8b05ab98b0> (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:288:in `installed_specs'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:84:in `specs'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:56:in `__materialize__'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `materialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `map!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:97:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/boot.rb:112:in `load_gems'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:6
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in `rails'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in `cloaker_'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:99:in `cloaker_'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/mongrel_rails:19
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
```

I am using cloud9 and have to deploy fedena school management project.

Comment: The Mongrel repo hasn't had an update in nearly a decade, and Fedena hasn't been touched in at least four years. I know for sure Mongrel is no longer supported and has been supplanted by other webservers. I would guess that Fedena is headed down the same path, so I think you might be well advised to cut your losses now.

Comment: Thats not the point I just need an open source school software and Fedena seems to be the obvious choice.

Comment: No, that *is* the point. If it's not supported, that means no one's using it. If no one is using it, you're not likely to receive help, as you will hopefully understand in short order. I'm not sure using ancient, unsupported software would be "the obvious choice" to me, but I'm sure you have your reasons. Best of luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command in your shell and try to run again

```
gem update --system 1.3.7
```